# Back Button Causes Application To Stop Responding

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

My application has two activities at the moment, a launch screen and an in game activity. The launch screen which is nothing but a background and a `Play` button. Pressing the play button starts the `InGameActivity`, which works properly with no problems. However, when I press the `back` button while in game it returns to the previous screen (the background and `Play` button are visible), but the app doesn't respond. After a few seconds an error message pops up asking to wait for it to respond or terminate.

In the game I use a thread to maintain a consistent 30 FPS and it controls the draw calls. My best bet is on the thread causing issues or something missing from the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I'm very confused. Everything I've found on the internet suggests that the back button rarely causes issues and calling `finish()` from `onPause()` or from `onBackPressed()` should take care of it, but it hasn't.

SOLUTION: Terminating the thread when onBackPressed() is called solved the problem.

The `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.title);

        play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.title_screen_play_button);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Play button pressed!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the in game activity:

```
public class InGameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("In game activity created");

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        //The GamePanel controls the entire game. It extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel(this, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, getResources());
        setContentView(gamePanel);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("Pausing game activity");

        finish();
    }

}
```

And the activities in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".InGameActivity"/>
```

Appreciate your help and taking the time to read this.

Let me know if any additional code is required to help.

Comment: calling finish() in onPause is one option but you can also add android:noHistory="true" to your Activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Calling `finish()` from `onPause()` is unnecessary unless you are modifying the default behaviour of `onBackPressed()`. Are you terminating your 30fps thread when `InGameActivity` finishes?

Comment: adelphus yes the issue was with a bug in the method to terminate the thread. Thank you for your response. I also removed finish() as it is unnecessary and everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Terminating the thread when onBackPressed() is called solved the problem.